# Webpack only one entry point?

Tags: webpack

I have two entry points for my webpack.config.js and so far it does what I expect in terms of building two separate files.  Is there a way for me to run the webpack command and have it build only ONE of those entry points instead of both?  For example, if I only make changes to files in teh second entry point, I don't want too have to wait for the first entry point to build as well.  Here's my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {app:'./src/Main.js',theme:'./src/Theme.js'},

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].bundle.js',
  path: 'build',
    publicPath: '/corp/build/'
  },
  plugins: [
    /*
        // This plugin minifies all the Javascript code of the final bundle
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle:   true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
            },
        }),
    */
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name:      'main', // Move dependencies to our main file
            children:  true, // Look for common dependencies in all children,
            minChunks: 2, // How many times a dependency must come up before being extracted
        })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass' ]},
      { test: /\.(jpg|gif|png|eot|woff|svg|ttf)(\?.*)?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried running `webpack --entry theme` but I get the error `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'theme' in /var/www/html/corp`

Answer (score 2):

You can make 2 separate Webpack config,

1. First with DLL Plugin For Theme entry point
2. In second bundle You can reference prebuilt theme via DLL Reference Plugin

and then you can run

`webpack --config _first.config_ && webpack --watch --config _second.config`

Any change in main code will not affect prebuilt theme bundle

https://robertknight.me.uk/posts/webpack-dll-plugins/

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/